# What is the best way to find out that access to the parent window has restrictions due to the same origin policy?

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, xss, same-origin-policy

My current solution:

```
function isAccessToWindowRestricted(w) {
  try {
    return !w.location.href;
  } catch (e) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Any better ideas? Is there a 'legal' way without try-catch?

Answer (score 3):

there is no good way, as there is no way to test that a value in the parent frame *even exists* without throwing an Exception.

I just tried a few things, including this:

```
var parentURL = window.parent && window.parent.location && window.parent.location.href;
```

and no matter what, it'll throw an Exception due to the same origin policy.  however, you can check to simply see if you're in an iframe

```
function checkInFrame( arg ){ arg = arg || window; return arg.parent == window; }
```

but to my knowledge you have to use a `try { ... } catch( ... ) { ... }` block (which is what it's there for).

Comment: Different browsers act differently. For example Chrome doesn't throw an exception and just returns undefined for location.href of the restricted window

Comment: good to know.  unfortunately, unless you're writing for just Chrome users, you'll still have to use a try / catch block, :(